# using an initializer list where the values contain unique_ptr member variables

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, initializer-list, stdmove

I have a class that contains a unique_ptr. I want to place instances of this class inside a container (specifically std::map). This works using `std::move` and `.emplace` however, I would like to perform all this initialization within the container's initializer list. Is this possible?

I suspect `Foo` gets initialized in the initializer list then copied which is causing the problem. I've tried added a `std::move` in the initializer list but that hasn't solved the problem.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<std::string> my_str_ptrs;
}
```

Compilation Fails "attempting to access a deleted function". **This is an example of what I want to do**

```cpp
std::map<std::string, Foo> my_map{
  {"a", Foo{}}
};
```

Compilation Succeeds

```cpp
std::map<std::string, Foo> my_map;
my_map.emplace("a", Foo{});
```

Comment: Change `std::unique_ptr<std::string> my_str_ptrs;` to `std::vector<std::string> my_strs`

Comment: What about writing a copy-constructor for `class Foo`, which will perform the copy from `Foo{}` in the way, you intend. For `std::unique_ptr` you can use cloning to perform the copy properly.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan, I tried this but got the same results.  Based on the answer from kaldrr , unless I change the std::initializer_list code, I don't think there is any way to make this work.

Comment: @J'e   I thought that as far as it will be bound to const lvalue ref, it would be  possible to clone the content of `my_str_ptrs` and the the copied variable should have a `std::unique_ptr` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fault of `std::initializer_list`, if you look at it's [begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin)/[end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/end) member functions, they return `const T*`, which means it will force `std::map` to try use the copy constructor of your `Foo`, which is `deleted` as `std::unique_ptr` can not be copied.

This issue is not unique to `std::map`, any container which allows you to initialize it with `std::initializer_list` will really copy the arguments from an initializer list.

The C++ standard requires that during such initialization there's a temporary `const T[N]` array, which the `std::initializer_list` points to, `const` disables moves from it.